# How to increase update performence with addToSet

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I have a collection with over 600000 records. All the records have the structure below (from my js console)

```
> db.invindex.find({_id: 'katar'}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "katar",
    "place" : [
        {
            "index" : [
                1
            ],
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53fd177620ba27591133387b")
        },
        {
            "index" : [
                396
            ],
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53dc621420ba2708ea53c0f5")
        },
        {
            "index" : [
                4
            ],
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e20c20ba271058d5c70c")
        },
        {
            "index" : [
                18,
                41
            ],
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e20220ba271055d5c705")
        },
        {
            "index" : [
                3
            ],
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e20420ba27105bd5c702")
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e25220ba271079318d44"),
            "index" : [
                21
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e43220ba271061d5c81a"),
            "index" : [
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e43320ba271061d5c81b"),
            "index" : [
                2,
                19
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e42f20ba27105bd5c7ff"),
            "index" : [
                23
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e4dd20ba27105bd5c860"),
            "index" : [
                8,
                24
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e63a20ba271076318ed4"),
            "index" : [
                6,
                18
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e63b20ba270ffd4533ea"),
            "index" : [
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6e65720ba270ffd4533f6"),
            "index" : [
                428
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6eacb20ba271073319162"),
            "index" : [
                22
            ]
        },
        {
            "pageid" : ObjectId("53f6ed5d20ba271003453786"),
            "index" : [
                304
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `place` field is what get updated frequent. I want to add some new record on the `place` sub-doc. Below is the python procedure of how I have accomplished it.

```
def update(doc, pos_list):
    add_to_set = {}
    add_to_set['place'] = {}
    add_to_set['place']['pageid'] = doc._id 
    add_to_set['place']['index'] = pos_list # eg, pos_list = [1,2,3]

    data = self.collection.find_one({'_id': _id})
    # Check if 'pageid' is already there in the record.
    # If not, then update

    self.collection.update(
                        {'_id': _id},
                        {'$addToSet': add_to_set},
                        upsert=upsert, 
                        w=1
                    )
```

But this update seems to be snail-slow! avr 1.3 sec per update. I'm running 10 child process to boost up the speed. But here is the `mongostat`

```
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0     25     19     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   691m    130 spider:65.1%          0       1|0     6|0     5k    63m    37   20:14:30 
    *0      2      1     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   629m    194 spider:10.8%          0       0|0     2|0   647b     8m    37   20:14:31 
    *0      5      8     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   650m     27 spider:71.9%          0       6|0     1|0     1k     4m    37   20:14:32 
    *0     15     15     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   654m    105 spider:52.4%          0       7|0     0|1     4k    32m    37   20:14:34 
    *0      9     12     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   666m     38 spider:53.9%          0      11|0     0|1     2k     7m    37   20:14:35 
    *0     16     13     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   633m    222 spider:46.6%          0       2|0     1|0     4k    40m    37   20:14:36 
    *0     10     11     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   666m    103 spider:39.5%          0       6|0     0|1     2k    22m    37   20:14:38 
    *0     13     15     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   655m     20 spider:90.0%          0      14|0     0|1     3k     1m    37   20:14:39 
    *0     18     17     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   672m    179 spider:48.5%          0       0|0     5|0     5k    47m    37   20:14:40 
    *0     12     15     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   661m    119 spider:40.2%          0       2|0     4|1     3k    15m    37   20:14:41 
insert  query update delete getmore command flushes mapped  vsize    res faults    locked db idx miss %     qr|qw   ar|aw  netIn netOut  conn       time 
    *0      9      8     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   682m    109 spider:27.5%          0       6|0     0|1     2k    32m    37   20:14:43 
    *0     19     21     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   659m    147 spider:85.6%          0       6|0     2|0     5k    20m    37   20:14:44 
    *0     15     20     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   684m    137 spider:63.1%          0       9|0     1|0     4k    12m    37   20:14:45 
    *0     18     13     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   634m    197 spider:39.0%          0       0|0     4|0     5k    51m    37   20:14:46 
    *0      6      6     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   638m    209 spider:13.9%          0       0|0     2|0     1k     3m    37   20:14:47 
    *0      4      9     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   641m    121 spider:37.4%          0      13|0     0|1   866b     3k    37   20:14:49 
    *0     19     15     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   618m    141 spider:50.7%          0       0|0     4|0     5k    58m    37   20:14:50 
    *0      2      3     *0       0     1|0       0  68.1g   137g   624m    181 spider:15.4%          0       6|0     0|1   528b   207k    37   20:14:51
```

My only index is the `_id` field. I have 4 GB of RAM. Now, my questions are

- Is this a normal speed?
- How can I boost up the update speed?

EDIT: My index

```
> db.invindex.stats()
{
    "ns" : "spider.invindex",
    "count" : 595306,
    "size" : 1302386304,
    "avgObjSize" : 2187,
    "storageSize" : 1580150784,
    "numExtents" : 19,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 415174656,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 25648112,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 25648112
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Why is "place.index" an array in itself? This does not make any sense. Also, thanks for the stats, but where are your indexes? Not really much use if you never bothered to index the field values you are querying on. Or even have excessive indexes on fields that cause a performance lag on insert or update. Please tell us the whole story here. Oh and fix that array mess I mentioned earlier. Just and advice point.

Comment: @NeilLunn `place.index` is the array of occurance of the `_id` on the document (identified by pageid). So it has to be an array (or a set). As I wrote on the question, my only index is the `_id` (I've added this log too!).

Comment: So getting on with it. What is the point? Presumably two "keys" and their values determine the set. This should be simple. Your performance stats point to a strong possibility that these "arrays/sets" have many members. How many? Quick tip here is if you are regularly going over 500 array/set entries then this is a bad thing. I would expect `$addToSet` in particular to "degrade" as the actual number increases towards this figure. But your turn to show before I show mine.

Comment: Do you really need `$addToSet`? Maybe you can fulfill your requirements using the much faster `$push`. The difference is that `$push` doesn't check if an identical entry already exists.

Comment: @Philipp but without any additional index (and a compound one) on the array fields the "cost" of "looking" for an "inequality" match to perform the same thing as `$addToSet` is probably worse. And not that much better with an index considering the additional update cost incurred. Trying to keep this about the "number of items in the 'set/array'" if you don't mind. Because that is likely the reason behind the performance numbers given.

Comment: @NeilLunn yes, the `place` fields can get up to 2000 (some rare case, 10000) or even more inner sets. But most of them has <10 sets in place.  And do I need to add any other key? Which would be my least expectation. @Philipp can you give me any performence benchmark between this two?

Comment: This would explain a lot as much as I have said, 500 is the real "drop off" point. Anything beyond that and performance degrades almost exponentially. So this is a real hard limit with MongoDB and arrays. Your requirements seem to suit a separate collection for these entries better. The cost of dealing with the additional request seem to outweigh the performance problems yo will see otherwise.

Comment: Would contruct and "answer" out of this but it is a bit messy. Short shrift is "Do not contruct arrays that exceed 500 elements per document".